# How to get the registration id in android by using gcm?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hi,

In my application I am using the gcm push notifications for sending notifications. I had implemented the following code in my project. For that, i created local database by using sq-lite in which i created one table.

But, now the problem is after running my application I wanted to get the registration id but registration id is not being stored. It shows as a null. Can anyone please help me?

**DatabaseHandlers.java:**

```
public class DatabaseHandlers extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FristRegistrationManager";

    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "firstregistration";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_STUDENTNAME = "studentname";
    private static final String KEY_CLASSID = "classid";
    private static final String KEY_ROLL_NO = "rollno";
    private static final String KEY_PARENTNAME = "parentname";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phno";
    private static final String KEY_GCM_REGID = "gcm_regid";

    public DatabaseHandlers(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_STUDENTNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CLASSID + " TEXT," + KEY_ROLL_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_PARENTNAME + " TEXT,"+ KEY_PH_NO +" TEXT,"+ KEY_GCM_REGID +" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    void addGSfeedback(GSfeedback contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_STUDENTNAME, contact.getStudentname());
        values.put(KEY_CLASSID, contact.getClassid());
        values.put(KEY_ROLL_NO, contact.getRollno());
        values.put(KEY_PARENTNAME, contact.getParentname());
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhnumber());   
        values.put(KEY_GCM_REGID, contact.getGcm_regid());  
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Context getApplicationContext() {

        return null;
    }


    GSfeedback getGSfeedback(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_STUDENTNAME,KEY_CLASSID,KEY_ROLL_NO,KEY_PARENTNAME,KEY_PH_NO,KEY_GCM_REGID}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        GSfeedback contact = new GSfeedback(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6));
        return contact;
    }

    public ArrayList<GSfeedback> getAllGSfeedbacks() {
        ArrayList<GSfeedback> contactList = new ArrayList<GSfeedback>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                GSfeedback contact = new GSfeedback();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setStudentname(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setClassid(cursor.getString(2));
                contact.setRollno(cursor.getString(3)); 
                contact.setParentname(cursor.getString(4)); 
                contact.setPhnumber(cursor.getString(5));
                contact.setGcm_regid(cursor.getString(6));  
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return contactList;
    }

    public int updateGSfeedback(GSfeedback contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_STUDENTNAME, contact.getStudentname());
        values.put(KEY_CLASSID, contact.getClassid());
        values.put(KEY_ROLL_NO, contact.getRollno());
        values.put(KEY_PARENTNAME, contact.getParentname());
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhnumber());
        values.put(KEY_GCM_REGID, contact.getGcm_regid());  

        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    }

    public void deleteGSfeedback(GSfeedback contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, null);
        db.close();
    }

    public int getGSfeedbacksCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();
        return cursor.getCount();
    }   
}
```

PopupRegistration.java:

```
public class PopupRegistration extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
private String[] state = { "class", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
        "9" };


public String log;
public DatabaseHandlers db;
List<String> list;

 EditText etName,etClass,etrollno,etparentname,etphno;

Button btnregister;

Spinner spinnerOsversions;

String PHONE_REGEX;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.popup_registration);

    db = new DatabaseHandlers(this);

    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etClass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etClass);
    etrollno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etrollno);
    etparentname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etparentname);
    etphno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etphno);

    btnregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerbutton);

    PHONE_REGEX = "[0-9]+";
    // spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    etClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    spinnerOsversions = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);



    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, state);

    adapter_state
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinnerOsversions.setAdapter(adapter_state);
    spinnerOsversions.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

    // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
    // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    final String gcm_regid = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    btnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (validate()) {
                 String studentname = etName.getText().toString();
                    String classid = spinnerOsversions.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String rollno = etrollno.getText().toString();
                    String parentname = etparentname.getText().toString();
                    String phno = etphno.getText().toString();

                // Save the Data in Database
                db.addGSfeedback(new GSfeedback(studentname,classid,rollno,parentname,phno,gcm_regid));
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Thanks for Registration, Welcome to Lilttle Flowers Public School Android App.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                etName.setText("");
                etClass.setText("");
                etrollno.setText("");
                etparentname.setText("");
                etphno.setText("");

                finish();

                Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Splashscreen.class);
                startActivity(nextScreen);
            }
        }

    });

}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.spinner:
        spinnerOsversions.setSelection(position);
        String selState = (String) spinnerOsversions.getSelectedItem();
        etClass.setText("" + selState);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}

private boolean validate() {
    String studentname = etName.getText().toString();
    String classid = spinnerOsversions.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String rollno = etrollno.getText().toString();
    String parentname = etparentname.getText().toString();
    String phno = etphno.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(studentname) || TextUtils.isEmpty(classid)
            || TextUtils.isEmpty(rollno) || TextUtils.isEmpty(parentname)
            || TextUtils.isEmpty(phno)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "pls fill the empty fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else if (etName.getText().toString().length() > 30
            && etparentname.getText().toString().length() > 30) {
        etName.setError("pls enter less the 30 charachter");
        return true;

    } else if (etphno.getText().toString().length() < 6
            || etphno.getText().toString().length() > 13) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter valid Phone Number",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else {
        if (etphno.getText().toString().trim().matches(PHONE_REGEX)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Enter Valid Phone Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this)` will return the registration ID only if you previously called `GCMRegistrar.register` and your broadcast receiver received the Registration ID in the async response and stored it in shared preferences. I don't see anywhere in your code where you actually register, so of course it will be null.

That said, it will be better not to use `GCMRegistrar` at all (it's deprecated) and instead use `GoogleCloudMessaging.register`. That's a blocking method, so you don't have to handle the response in a separate place.

Comment: Now what i will do can you please tell me

Comment: In where i have to add the shared preference code.its already in jar file only

Comment: Hi please tell me I am waiting for your reply

Comment: @user3640092 Use the [demo app](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/GcmClient/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java) as an example.